# How can I show only these attributes on frontend that will be only checked in magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes

[image]

How can I show only these attributes on frontend that will be only checked in magento2?

Comment: these attributes are custom i want to show only those attributes on listing page that will be selected for listing page in magento 2

Comment: This looks like some sort of module, which module you are using?

Comment: custom module advance attribute lists

Comment: just now i have to show selected attributes on frontend